# stringLowerCase filter to apply on ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I'm defining a pipes example in my application, which transforms the uppercase string to lowercase ex: **'Activities' => 'activities**'. And the data is in the Array format and I am applying this filter on `*ngFor`. It returns me an error saying '`toLowerString` is not a function', Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

[**Demo link**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bhs7ke)

Comment: Why don't you simply use the pre-defined pipe in angular for lowercase ? Example : let caption of captions | lowercase

Comment: @SoujanyaJ i think you need to `{{ Abc | lowercase}}` check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xu5e8s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @ThanveerShah got it right, here is the link, https://angular.io/api/common/LowerCasePipe#lowercasepipe

Comment: @Soujanya - you should use pre-defined pipe like {{option | lowercase}} rather than creating complex pipe over array. make your project simple and faster

Comment: Thank you for all your responses, I am actually trying to build a table component. And I wanted to transform the col to lowercase is to map to my dataset, so as to construct records. Can you please have a look at the updated source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) is usable only on `string` data type. Which to said you need to make sure that the data was a `string` with: [`.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

```
value.toString().toLowerCase()
```

With that being said as [Thanveer Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10866113/thanveer-shah) have been said in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820924/stringlowercase-filter-to-apply-on-ngfor/54820990#comment96416946_54820924) you can use `| lowercase` which are inbuilt to transform into a string.

See [Fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwnt8q?file=src/app/lower-case.pipe.ts) for both versions being in used.

---

Clarification:
Intentionally used the following code:

```
export class LowerCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) {
    console.log(value.toString().toLowerCase());
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
      value[i] = value[i].toString().toLowerCase();
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

to show that the data was an array.

But if you already understand that it was an array you could simply use:

```
export class LowerCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(value: Array<string>) {
      return value.map((x)=>{ return x.toLowerCase() })
    }
}
```

as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54821061/3654837) by [Ferhad Othman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8677015/ferhad-othman).

Comment: thank you so much, I got your point, but I am actually trying to build a table component. And I wanted to transform the col to lowercase is to map to my dataset, so as to construct records. Can you please have a look at the updated source code.

Comment: Simple. Just implement my method there see the [forked update](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-st1ujz?file=src/app/lower-case.pipe.ts)

Comment: I got the needed output, Small question, when I am already in a loop i.e NgFor, what is the need to add another for loop in the pip transform function? We could just pass the text param and convert into lowercase and send it back. I didn't get the reason behind this.

Comment: There is no real need honestly. It just to make it easier for you to know that the datatype was actually an array.

Comment: @Mykyuu I will be happy to know the reason.

Answer (score 5):

```
<li *ngFor="let caption of captions">
    {{caption | lowercase }}
</li>

<li *ngFor="let caption of captions">
    {{caption | uppercase }}
</li>

<li *ngFor="let caption of captions">
    {{caption | titlecase }}
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for all your responses, I am actually trying to build a table component. And I wanted to transform the col to lowercase is to map to my dataset, so as to construct records. Please find the updated source code.

Comment: I was looking for `titlecase` I saw it in docs - I added it there.  It might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `value.toLowerCase()`, because value seems tobe an array not a string. So The value must be type Array not string and you must return an array not console.log.
try this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ 
    name: 'stringLowerCase' 
})
export class LowerCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Array<string>) {
      return value.map((x)=>{ return x.toLowerCase() })
    }
}
```

Comment: There is already `lowercase` pipe exist; then why bother :-) https://angular.io/api/common/LowerCasePipe#lowercasepipe

Comment: In this link is used by expression not *ngFor

Comment: I mean after *ngFor ecentually result is supposed to be printed in template `{{output}}`, so then simple pipe will work fine in that case. rather create pipe and register in module so provide in further dependencies

Comment: I know, but I answered his question, I solved what he is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply your custom pipe like below it will work.

```
 <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let caption of captions ">
            {{caption | stringLowerCase }}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And in your pipe return after value tranform like below.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ 
    name: 'stringLowerCase' 
})
export class LowerCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string) {
        console.log(value.toString().toLowerCase());
        return value.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

**[Here is forked solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qknqku?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: why not use built in `lowercase` pipe :)

Comment: yes but he might do some extra string operation then custom pipe is more useful

Answer (score 0):

```
<li *ngFor="let caption of captions">
    {{caption | lowercase }}
</li>
```

Comment: While this code might be the solution, as a good answer it really needs an explanation of why it works.